# How to pass data to client out of "app.get"?

Tags: node.js, express

How to pass data to client out of "app.get"?

There are 2 server(front, back)

Clients connect to the front server,

front server to back server, back server to DB

When a client logs in front server

front server pass the request to back server

back server search log in information from DB

after search, back server return result to front server

However, because the front server http server

```
app.get ("/ login /: ID / Password), function (request, response) {
// send to login data to back server
// because I dont know DB result i can't response now by 'response' variable
};
```

when front server received the result of log in

the code is out of "app.get"

so I can't access response variable
( like response.end( "result" ) )

How do I pass result of log in to client?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your response back to client side with the help of `response` object.

```
app.get("/ login /: ID / Password), function (request, response) {
        // send login data back to client side
        var loginData = {
            name: 'admin',
            password: 'admin'
        }
        console.log(loginData);
        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/json'
        });
        response.write(loginData);
        response.end();
};
```

**EDITED POST: POST A REQUEST TO ANOTHER BACKEND SERVER**

For that, you need to add `request` module of `node.js` into `package.json`.

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "request": "*"
    }
}
```

Now, update it with terminal using `npm update` command. `request` module is now added to your `node_modules` folder.

Its time to call your backend server.

```
app.get("/ login /: ID / Password), function (request, response) {

        // import request module
        var request = require("request");
        request({
            uri: '', // pass your url
            method: "POST", // GET/POST
            form: request.body // contains data (login/password) which you sent from client side
        }, function(error, resp, body) {
            console.log(body);
            response.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/json'
            });
            response.write(body);
            response.end();
        });
};
```

Comment: thanks for answer
but I want to response back to client after checking DB so i cant response immediately
when result of log in return from back server to front server
i cant use response variable

Comment: look at the edited post. For that, you need to add `request` module into your project.